# Failed to build an iOS Swift project when running scan in Fastlane

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane

I'm trying to build an iOS project in Fastlane. Here is my *Fastfile*:

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Description of what the lane does"
  lane :metrics do

    scan(scheme: "ABC", 
      code_coverage: true, 
      derived_data_path: "./DerivedData", 
      output_directory: "./sonar-reports",
      configuration: "Debug",
      workspace: "ABC.xcworkspace",
      sdk: "iphonesimulator",
      destination: "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 15,OS=17.0.1"
    )     
end
end
```

When I run `fastlane metrics`, I got the following error message:

> ** BUILD FAILED **
> The following build commands failed:
> CodeSign /Users/user/ABC/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MJRefresh/MJRefresh.framework (in target 'MJRefresh' from project 'Pods')
> CodeSign /Users/user/ABC/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/INTULocationManager/INTULocationManager.framework (in target 'INTULocationManager' from project 'Pods')
> CodeSign /Users/user/ABC/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC/FBLPromises.framework (in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')

Apparently it fails in my Podfiles. Really don't understand why there is a CodeSign error for Pods project for simulator in Debug mode. But it's fine to run my project in Xcode or build with `xcodebuild` command:

```
xcodxcodebuild \
  -workspace ABC.xcworkspace \
  -scheme "ABC" \  
  -sdk iphonesimulator \
  -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 15,OS=17.0.1' \
  test
```

I think there must be something wrong in my `Fastfile` configuration. Can anybody suggest what I should do? Thanks.

Comment: I solved the issue by moving my project from OneDrive folder into my ~/Project folder.